# SAS - reading from .dat file only getting first observation on each line

Tags: sas

I have a .dat file structured as such:

```
1/1/1987    17345.9 30798.5 2/1/1987    18853.9 29810.3 3/1/1987    21835.5 32464.3 4/1/1987    20677.7 32291.1 5/1/1987    20759.5 33170
```

The delimiting seems somewhat irregular. When opened in notepad, it appears that there is only one space between all of the variables. I.e. one right arrow key press to move between any variable.

I am trying to create a data set as such:

```
data temp;
infile 'C:\filepath\file.dat' missover dlm = '09'x;
input month exports imports;
informat month mmddyy10.;
format month mmddyy10. exports dollar10.2 imports dollar10.2 balance dollar10.2;
balance = exports - imports;
run;
```

This seems to only be grabbing the first observation on each line of the file. I'm really not sure how this is delimited or how to handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have multiple observations per line of raw data, you can use double trailing at signs (@@) at the end of your input statement.

Try:

```
input month exports imports @@;
```